# gameObject.CompareTag no funciona en mi código

Tags: c#, script, unity

estoy haciendo un código que se tienen que destruir ciertos objetos con diferentes Tags y si un objeto en particular se destruye pierdes el juego, el problema va en que el CompareTag por algún motivo no funciona, estoy aprendiendo recién el c#.

script condicionGanar, esta ligado a un objeto vacio

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class condicionGanar : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int bloquesDestruidos = 0;
   public int bloquesRojosDestruidos = 0;
   public int bloquesRojoNecesarios = 0;

public void ObjetoDestruido()
{
    bloquesDestruidos++;
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("rojo"))
    {
        bloquesRojosDestruidos++;
        Debug.Log("Destruiste el bloque rojo");
    }
    else if (gameObject.CompareTag("verde"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Has perdido");
    }
  }


void Update()
{
    if (bloquesRojosDestruidos == bloquesRojoNecesarios)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pasaste al siguiente nivel");
    }
}
```

}

Script destruirBloque, este si funciona correctamente

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class destruirBloque : MonoBehaviour
{   
     void OnMouseDown()
{
    // Comprobar si el objeto tiene la etiqueta deseada
    if (gameObject.tag == "rojo" || gameObject.tag == "azul")
    {
        // Destruir el objeto
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    FindObjectOfType<condicionGanar>().ObjetoDestruido();
}
}
```

Los Tags estan correctamente creados y solo aumenta el int bloquesDestruidos por lo que el if del metodo ObjetoDestruido es el problema

Comment: Y si pones `Debug.Log(gameObject.tag);` antes de los `if`, que aparece?

Comment: lo acabo de intentar y sale Untagged, puede ser que lo que este arrojando sea el Tag del objeto vacío al que le añadí el script y no lo este tomando del bloque, en tal caso no sabria como hacerlo

Comment: El problema debe estar en que no le pusiste el tag al gameobject